# Solving the problem with flexbox layout in SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm learning HTML and CSS (SCSS) and several times I get into contact with following issue:

The problem and the solution is probably very simple, but I wasn't able to solve it until now and I'd like to do it properly in the future projects.

I have a flexbox with basically two elements - logo on the left side and some title and description on the right side. There is some spacing between them but the problem is when the logos have variable widths. My goal is to have logo on the left side of the flexbox and the title and decription on the right side with text-align left and when there are several rows of same flexboxes in the mobile layout the line where the text starts should be the same in all of them.

I tried to solve this with setting some flex-grows, setting margins on .svg or text, I also tried to play a bit with justify-content, but the different width of logos is moving with the text all the time.

Thanks for your support.

```css
// Services
.service {
  display: flex;
  background-color: $light-grey;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.service__title {
  color: $primary;
}

.service__text {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="service">
  <img class="service__logo" src="images/map.svg" alt="Logo of pointer in the map">

  <div class="service__text">
    <h3 class="service__title">Podpora na místě</h3>
    <p class="service__descripton">V cílové destinaci jsou k dispozici naši delegáti, kteří vám vždy rádi poradí.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the perfect job for a `grid` layout, not a `flexbox` one. If you want to keep using `flexbox`, you should have the same width for all logos.

Comment: Hi, thanks. In the end I solved it by using display: grid and setting justify-self: center and align-self: start to the logo. Hope that's going to be no problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "justify-content: space-evenly;" style  under the "display: flex" to the service class in your CSS.
I think this should solve the problem.
Then adjust the padding/ margin of your image/logo to keep the logo description at a reasonable distance.
Also set your logo at a fixed height and width to prevent it from increasing/decreasing with the flex.
It's advisable to use an image/logo container class for that.